# Redirect to another port in iptables shows no chain error

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I'm facing strange problem with iptables right now. Simply, I want to redirect traffic from port 514 to port 5140. I'm using this IPTables command to achieve it:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5140
```

But I still get error about no chain

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

There is definitelly PREROUTING chain in nat table, this is iptables -t nat -nL

```
root@VPS-LOGGER-TMP:~# iptables -t nat -nL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm using Debian Wheezy and I have loaded all needed modules:

```
root@VPS-LOGGER-TMP:~# lsmod |grep nat
iptable_nat            12928  0 
nf_nat                 18242  1 iptable_nat
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14078  4 nf_nat,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           52720  4 xt_state,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,iptable_nat
ip_tables              22042  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               19118  9 ip_tables,iptable_filter,xt_multiport,ip6_tables,ip6table_filter,xt_state,xt_tcpudp,ipt_REJECT,iptable_nat
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? As far as I know this should work perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you by any chance running inside a containerised environment?

Comment: It is GoGrid cloud server which should be VM based on XEN afaik. I've tried it on different VM and it works without problem.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work here, so telling me it works elsewhere is no help.  You **don't** have all the needed kernel modules loaded - on my systems, the module `ipt_REDIRECT` is needed, and it is force-loaded on demand.  *If* you were running in a container, then you wouldn't be able to load that module, and that would exactly explain the results you observe.  I'd ask my hosting provider what the *actual* hosting technology applicable to this server is (GoGrid seem to offer a number).

Comment: So it is very, very strange at all....I've add proper DNS records for this machine and now I can load ipt_REDIRECT module without any problem. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT
```

set to y or m in your kernel configuration in order to use -j REDIRECT.

The module would be called xt_REDIRECT, and that seems to be missing on your machine.

Comment: I already have it set on m. I'm using default debian kernet without any modification from my side

Comment: We are kind of overlapping. Try to load xt_REDIRECT, it seems not to be loaded yet.